# Advanced Search answer wording

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, faq-update-request

From this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10934/search-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/50235#50235) Jeff said, "answers:0 is a bit of a special case; it returns questions with no answers".  Could we please get that added to the advanced search page?

Comment: It's implied with the current wording isn't it?

Comment: @Chris: No, as stated on the search page, it would return questions with >= 0 answers (i.e., everything), instead of == 0 answers like it actually does.

Comment: @Jon - ah, sorry, yes it does need clearing up then ;)

Comment: Definitely for this. We already have the 0 cases listed for the (or not) variants of several other advanced searches.

Comment: @Jon, thanks for the tag correction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I updated the faq; this will be rolled out within 24 hours.